# Grunt distribution doesn't include node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gruntjs

I'm writing an application using Grunt as my build tool.  I used the Yeoman generator angular-fullstack.  The app is a Node.js app with Express on the backend.  While developing, things work fine.  If I build the distribution though, I can't deploy it to my server because none of the required npm dependencies are available, like Express for example.  It's the first time I build this kind of app, so I assume I'm missing a step since the Gruntfile.js is still all defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "node_modules" folder is traditionally not included into source code repositories, for various reasons.

If you set up your node application correctly, however, and you have a "package.json" file where all dependencies are listed, then you just need to run `npm install` to download and install npm modules.